# How to prevent matplotlib figure is resized due to outside legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got a general issue with a plotting function using matplotlib.pyplot. I plot a set of stacked horizontal bar charts, the goal is to produce congruent figures, the embedded grid is suppose to fit, but the image gets resized, when I change the input data. However, if i plot the image without the legend, I receive the desired output. But I do want to include a legend of course !
The formatting lines I include are the following:

**figure size**

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(20,9))
```

**grid definition**

```
plt.grid(color="darkgrey")
```

**legend defintion**

```
ax.legend([handles[i] for i in order], [labels[i] for i in order],
              bbox_to_anchor=((0.5, -0.15)), loc="upper center",fontsize="medium",ncol=5)
```

**tight layout**

```
fig.tight_layout()
```

**store the image**

```
fig.savefig(str(figname)+'.jpg',bbox_inches='tight',quality=95,dpi=300)
```

Comment: Don’t do bbox_inches=‘tight’

Comment: then my legend gets cut. the plot shifts and shrinks its relationship with different legend entries apparently ..

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html Bbox_inches =“tight” expands or contracts the size of the figure to match the artists.  You can’t magically have everything stay the same size. If you need large legends place the legend somewhere that it won’t overspill the plot.  (Or better, dont use large legends)